# autocomplete textbox .NET doesn't work

Tags: asp.net

part of My aspx page

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" id= "TextBox1"  ></asp:TextBox>
    <ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender
                runat="server" TargetControlID="TextBox1"
                MinimumPrefixLength="0" ServiceMethod="getAutoComplete()"
                ServicePath="nationality.aspx.cs"                  
                >

</ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

my aspx.cs code:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethodAttribute(), System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethodAttribute()]
public static string[] getAutoComlete(string prefixText, int count, string contextKey)
{
     string[] a = { "11", "22", "33" };
     return a;
}
```

I am trying to make autocomplete .
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312318/how-can-i-get-my-autocomplete-extender-to-work?rq=1

Comment: saw this topic have done what they say no effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethodAttribute(), System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethodAttribute()]
    public static string[] getAutoComplete(string prefixText, int count, string contextKey)
    {
string[] a = { "11", "22", "33" };
            return a;
    }
```

You are not using the samename function on the aspx page and the C# code :)

Comment: Sorry Improved that `[System.Web.Services.WebMethodAttribute(), System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethodAttribute()]
        public static string[] getAutoComplete(string prefixText, int count, string contextKey)
        {
    string[] a = { "11", "22", "33" };
                return a;
        }
`      Still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

If you have your service code on same page of your control, then it will directly call your service code.

```
  try below,

//change asp page like this

<asp:TextBox runat="server" id= "TextBox1"  ></asp:TextBox>
    <ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender
                runat="server" TargetControlID="TextBox1"
                MinimumPrefixLength="0" ServiceMethod="getAutoComplete">
</ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>

// change your .cs code as below

[System.Web.Services.WebMethod(true)]
public static string[] GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count)
{
     string[] a = { "11", "22", "33" };
     return a;
}

Hope it helps.
```

Comment: Did doesn't work too but i don't understand this:'service code on same page of your control' is my control is on nationality.aspx and code on nationality aspx.cs there are on different pages?

Comment: I mean your service code is on code side, and control on design side of same page, then you don't need to specify service path. It will automatically call it.

Comment: ok. now remove this [System.Web.Services.WebMethodAttribute(), System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethodAttribute()] and add instead [System.Web.Services.WebMethod(true)]. Check updated code. May be now work.